# Avoid identical substrings of length $j$ in a string of length $N$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to quantify the "difficulty" of having a given PCRE (perl-compatible regular expression) **not** matching a random input.
EDIT : I'm speaking of **(\w{i}).*\1** where \1 is a back-reference to the substring \w{i} prevously captured.

If I turn this problem into combinatorics, at one point  I'm facing this question:

$a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_{n}$ is a sequence where $a_i\in [0;M]$

$j \leq n$ is the length of a substring of $(a_i)$. I want to compute the number $S_{M,N,j}$ of possibilities to **not** have $1 \leq k, k'\leq n-j+1$ such that

$a_ka_{k+1}\cdots a_{k+j-1}$ and 
$a_{k'}a_{k'+1}\cdots a_{k'+j-1}$ are the same substring.

I don't know how to cope with all these parameters.  My idea is not necessarily to find an exact formula for $S$, but to understand how to maximize it when $j,M,N$ vary.

If anyone could point me in a promising direction, I would truly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, where does the regular expression enter the picture? Later on you seem to speak about a string containing a repeated substring of length $j$, which doesn't seem to have a simple connection to regular expressions.

Comment: The regex I'm playing with is the following : (\w{i}).*\1 
where \w is a shortuct for [A-Za-z0-9_]. \w{i} is the substring which must appears 2 times. 
I would like to understand the influence of the parameter i. Actually I ran some tests against a base64-random input and it seems that the maximum time of execution (searching for a match) is obtained when i=4 or 5.

Comment: x @Bernard: Note that something with a backreference in it is _not_ considered a "regular expression" within formal language theory, so it is somewhat confusing to use that word in a mathematical context. Are you looking to maximize the _number of different strings_ that don't have repeated substrings, or the _running time of a particular matching engine_? Those are not necessarily the same.

Comment: You're right, I'll edit to clarify. 
I'm trying to maximize the number of strings that don't have repeated substrings. The way the particular matching engine I'm using is coded makes me think that the running time will then be maximized, and that's what I want. Thanks.